# Creating a user via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to perform this curl request

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {BEARER_TOKEN}' \
--data-raw '{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "test666@mytennant.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password"
  }
}'
```

I keep getting

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-10-23T14:01:06",
            "request-id": "caf9e0be-88fc-4a4e-a6eb-fed1ccedb90c",
            "client-request-id": "caf9e0be-88fc-4a4e-a6eb-fed1ccedb90c"
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following permissions set on the app registration
[image]

Can someone please help me figure out what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you are provided it seems to be you are not having right permission to create the user.

In the token, you are missing the permissions, so before making the graph request you need to have the token with

```
User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All.
```

[image]

I made the below request, without having  the required permission then I received the same error as you can see below
[image]

Then later  I added the permissions and requested for the new token, then made the graph call. Now I was successfully able to create the user
[image]
[image]

**Curl**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{​​​​ "accountEnabled": true, "displayName": "displayName-value", "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value", "userPrincipalName": "upn-value1@xx.live", "passwordProfile" : {​​​​ "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true, "password": "xx@123" }​​​​ }​​​​'
```